# Como capturar parâmetros passados pela URL usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Como capturar parâmetros passados pela `URL` (Método GET) usando javascript? também é possível capturar parâmetros passados via Método POST?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Os dados que forem passados via **POST** estão somente disponiveis no lado do servidor.
O Browser não os passa para o JavaScript/cliente.

Os dados **GET** podem ler-se da `url`. Nõ há uma ferramenta nativa para isso como no *PHP* ou *Node.js*. O método é mais ou menos ler essa *string* partindo-a em pedaços.

Para ler a string GET/query da `url` pode usar-se `location.search` que dá a a parte começada pelo `?`. Depois tem de se agrupar por chave valor. A sintaxe da query é:

> ?**chave**=valor&**outraChave**=outroValor& ... etc

O `?` inicia a *string*, o `&` separa cada grupo de chave e valor.

Um exemplo seria `meusite.com/?lang=pt&page=home`. Para retirar estes parametros para um objeto por exemplo pode fazer-se assim:

```
var query = location.search.slice(1);
var partes = query.split('&');
var data = {};
partes.forEach(function (parte) {
    var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
    var chave = chaveValor[0];
    var valor = chaveValor[1];
    data[chave] = valor;
});

console.log(data); // Object {lang: "pt", page: "home"}
```

#### Exemplo: http://output.jsbin.com/qawiyiqisu/1/?lang=pt&page=home