# Como mudar uma imagem de acordo com o parâmetro da url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como mudar uma imagem de acordo com o parâmetro da url.

exemplo:
quero que nessa url mostre a imagem http://www.duloren.com.br/colecao/?fq=H:321
e em outra url como por exemplo http://www.duloren.com.br/colecao/?fq=H:150 não apareça.
sendo que a pagina principal é unica e só o parametro de busca que muda.

Comment: Por favor descreva melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Tenho que mostrar um banner em apenas uma url, porém o que diferencia uma url de outra são parametros, pois é uma busca...
queria saber se tem um script que tenha uma condição que eu possa alterar o banner de acordo com o parametro da url.

Comment: Use essa solução para capturar os parametros da URL com o Jquery: (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65696/como-capturar-parâmetros-passados-pela-url-usando-javascript)
Com o paremetro desejado utilize o Ajax para pegar a imagem

Comment: Não deixe de ler esse post  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

Essa linha de CSS para esconder a div que contém a imagem, pois o JavaScript será usado para mostrar o conteúdo dessa div quando desejado.

```
.minhaDiv {
   display:none;
}
```

**O Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Analise o parâmetro do URL
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // obtem o parametro fq
    var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('fq');

     $(document).ready(function() {

        // Checa se o parametro é H:321
        if (dynamicContent == 'H:321') {
            $('#mostra').show();
        } 
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="mostra" class="minhaDiv">
    <img src="Sua_Imagem.ext">
 </div>
```

Exemplos:

[**?fq=H:321**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/exibir-conteudo-dinamico-usando-parametro-url.htm?fq=H:321)

[**?fq=H:150**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/exibir-conteudo-dinamico-usando-parametro-url.htm?fq=H:150)