# Recuperar dinamicamente todos os GET da URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou carregando dinamicamente minhas views com ajax utilizando:

```
view = getUrlParameter('view') ? getUrlParameter('view') : window.location.href+="?view=newusers";

$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  url: "views/empregador/" + view + ".php",
  data: {
    auth: 'ajaxrequest'
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#viewa').html(data);
});
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente para casos em que acesso uma página que não precisa de parâmetros GET. Porém, em algumas requisições preciso preciso que minha url seja `"views/empregador/" + view + ".php?meuGet=123&meuOutroGetAleatorio=123&..."`.

A minha função getUrlParameter recupera parâmetros específicos da URL, forçando uma verificação se 1 por 1 existe, que seria totalmente inviável para o nível de complexidade aplicação.

Existe algum método de capturar de forma dinamica todos os GETs passados pela URL com javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar a função location.search para pegar a query completa:

```
 var query = location.search;
```

Caso queira manipula-lás, já existe uma resposta em tópico respondendo isso:
[Como capturar parâmetros passados pela URL usando javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65696/como-capturar-par%C3%A2metros-passados-pela-url-usando-javascript)