# Acessar e altera conteudo de ID por url?

Tags: javascript, html, json, div

Estou fazendo alguns testes com a `API` do BLOGGER e nos testes que realizei consegui chegar até determinado ponto que é adicionar conteúdo aos artigos via `API`.

Pagina onde estou fazendo meus testes:

> `https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/publish`

No entanto gostaria de fazer uma alteração nesse script.

Veja:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for blogger.posts.insert
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/blogger/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.blogger.posts.insert({
      "blogId": "blogId",
      "resource": {
        "content": "\n&lt;div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; display: none; text-align: center;\"&gt;\n&lt;object class=\"BLOG_video_class\" contentid=\"ID\" height=\"266\" id=\"BLOG_video-ID\" width=\"320\"&gt;&lt;/object&gt;\n&lt;br /&gt;\nID&lt;br /&gt;\n&lt;br /&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n\t"
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>

<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

O código que o site me forneceu tem uma Button para rodar o script, teria como rodar o script por url direto? hospedando o script acessando ele?

Na parte do conteúdo do artigo precisaria enviar esse código do jeito que está, mas altera apenas a "ID", eu teria que edita o código sempre que fosse executar ele, veja que tem 3 ID nesse código:

> `"content": "\n&lt;div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; display: none; text-align: center;\"&gt;\n&lt;object class=\"BLOG_video_class\" contentid=\"**ID**\" height=\"266\" id=\"BLOG_video-**ID**\" width=\"320\"&gt;&lt;/object&gt;\n&lt;br /&gt;\n**ID**&lt;br /&gt;\n&lt;br /&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n\t"`

Seria possível altera essas ID direto na `url` de execução?

Exemplo:

> `http://site/meuscritpt.com/?ID= nova-ID`

Conforme fosse alterada a ID na `url` o efeito seria o mesmo dentro do script.

A um tempo atrás eu vi algo parecido aqui no site mas não estou encontrando mais.

Comment: Não está claro o que realmente precisa, muito amplo o assunto, poderia criar um exemplo minimo?

Comment: Estou tentando acessar os videos enviados ao blogger por url com um link direto como esse exemplo : https://tudogostoso.blog/make/check/?list=e6dac2f91a67e518  essa letras finais após list= é a ID do video , se vc por qualquer numero ou letra no lugar da ID vc consegue ver o codigo que faz a requisição do video, o codigo é uma API do blogger que é o SCRIPT acima que coloquei na pergunta.  vou reforma a pergunta para ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Refiz a pergunta aqui  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414450/acessar-conte%c3%bado-atr%c3%a1ves-de-api-blogger

Answer (score 0):

Aqui esta os comando que você consegue pegar um parametro passado por get com javascript

var query = location.search.slice(1);
var partes = query.split('&');
var data = {};
partes.forEach(function (parte) {
    var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
    var chave = chaveValor[0];
    var valor = chaveValor[1];
    data[chave] = valor;
});

console.log(data[nome da variavel passado por get]);

Como descrito no link abaixo:
[Como capturar parâmetros passados pela URL usando javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65696/como-capturar-par%C3%A2metros-passados-pela-url-usando-javascript)

Com isso você vai conseguir colocar o id onde quiser via JavaScript usando a variável Data
Espero ter ajudado
Att

Comment: refiz a pergunta aqui  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414450/acessar-conte%c3%bado-atr%c3%a1ves-de-api-blogger